# Datadog custom span tags are only working for one of the request but not working for the other requests in Datadog

Tags: datadog

Datadog span tags are only working for the one requests but not working for the other requests in Datadog

final Span span = GlobalTracer.get().activeSpan();

```
if (span != null)
{
    LOGGER.debug(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, "GlobalTracer.activeSpan non-null.");

    span.setTag(USERNAME, obj.getName());
}
```

[EVENT UNSPECIFIED -> /com.abc.tax.gdsvb.classname] GlobalTracer.activeSpan non-null.

I am expecting to work for all the requests

Comment: i have the same bug here. I am using custom span. When I restart my app trace are send but then it stops i don't know why.